# Meta viewport is changing jquery function behavior

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a loading gif to show when a button is clicked using jquery.  Everything works fine until I add this meta tag to the head section of my code.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(window).load(function() {
$(".loader").show(); 
$(".loader").fadeOut("slow");

})



$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btnSun').click(showLoader);
});
function showLoader() { 
 $(".loader").show(); 
 $(".loader").fadeOut(10000);

}



</script>


<style>
.loader {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
background: url('https://roofcentrix.com/images/loading.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
display: none;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="loader"></div>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="generate">
<button id="btnSun">Test!</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the PHP (All code is on same page)

```
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
$run = "SELECT * FROM customers";
// Code to generate a pdf using mpdf is ran here...

}
```

Basically, without the meta viewport tag, when I submit the form, it works fine.  The loading icon comes up and when the pdf script is finished, it goes away like I would like it to do.

When I try it WITH the meta viewport.  It does nothing but submit the form.  Once the pdf is FINISHED the loading icon shows.  I am assuming is showing from the window load function at that point.  But at that point it is to late anyways and is useless to what I am trying to do.  I know for sure btnSun function is still being fired as I added an alert script, and sure enough I get the alert but the loading icon doesn't show like it does if the meta tag is not there.

Does anyone know what could possibly be causing this?  I have searched for days trying to find an answer and just cannot figure it out.  I also had a page that would hide and show a button using jQuery.  The meta viewport tag also caused that jQuery function not to change the button properly anymore as well.

Please help and huge thanks if you can!

EDIT: After testing further it only seems to be an issue on Firefox mobile

Comment: Well if you take a look at [jQuery Browser Support](https://jquery.com/browser-support/), then you'll notice that Firefox mobile isn't listed. If you're lucky you might find someone that had the same issue in the past and created a solution for it. But it's safe to assume that this isn't a programming issue. It's a compatability issue. You might also try updating to jQuery 3.0

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Sorry to waste your time with such an obvious answer.

Comment: Asking a good and serious question is never wasting anyone's time. I prefer reading these kinds of questions ten times over `How do I? ...` without any research efford at all :)

Comment: Thanks.  One more question if I could.  Sorry I am a newby I just have to ask.  If it is a JQuery compatibility issue, then why does it work correctly in Firefox Mobile when the Meta Viewport is not in place?

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell you. If I did know the answer, I would've known a solution. It's the very nature of compatibility issues. Something works in certain cases, but fails on others. I don't understand all the inner workings of jQuery. It might work differently with viewports. I would suggest testing it on the stock Android browser. If it works fine there, it's safe to assume it really is an issue with jQuery and Firefox mobile

Comment: But to tell you the truth, I don't do fancy rings and bells for mobile websites. As you've just noticed yourself, the mobile web market is still very young. It's developing incredibly fast, but still has a lot of limitations compared to computer browsers. Trying to get everything to work exactly the same on every browser and every machine is a very, very long road through hell

Comment: On a side note, after doing some research for you, it seems that it's indeed a known problem with jQuery and Firefox Mobile Viewports. A temporary solution would be to use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">` instead. Read here: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-meta-viewport-problem-in-firefox-fennec